# Custom xml with drawable and depended location

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable

Image with the desired layout:

[image]I have the following situation:

I have group which contains buttons that are populated from database(for example, 10 items in the specific table will populate 10 buttons in this group) - that works fine.

The parts that I don't know how to do is:

- I wold like that this buttons will shows as a circle (Drawable) and within that circle there is an image (the path will be taken from the database) and a label from the above explanation(from a table).
- If there is a one item, it will be in the center of the screen and as the amount of the buttons growth, the circles will set within a Grid of 3 columns.

Can someone help me with this issues?

the older version where I try deferent method (with RadioButtons), in this example there is no Image or drawable and the items are a radioButtons within RadioGroup:

```
DatBas dbc = new DatBas(Tamar_appActivity.this);
    dbc.open();
    SQLiteDatabase tdb = dbc.getDatabase();
    String[] columns = new String[] { DatBas.KEY_ROW_B_ID,
            DatBas.KEY_B_NAME };
    Cursor c = tdb.query(DatBas.DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    int iRawBId = c.getColumnIndex(DatBas.KEY_ROW_ID);
    int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(DatBas.KEY_B_NAME);

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {

        RadioGroup radiogroup = (RadioGroup)   
                    findViewById(R.id.bNameSelectGroup);
        final Button rdbtn = new Button(this);

        rdbtn.setId(iRawBId);
        rdbtn.setText(c.getString(iBName));
        radiogroup.addView(rdbtn);
    }
    dbc.close();

}
```

This is the SpacialButton.java code:

```
public class SpecialButton extends RelativeLayout {

public TextView text;
//public ImageView image;

public SpecialButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cb_shape);
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cb_inner,
            this, true);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
//    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBB);
}

public SpecialButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SpecialButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

}
```

This is the cb_inner.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- This will hold the image from the database -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageBB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <!-- This will be the label. It will be placed below the center -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cbTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</merge>
```

This is the Main.java code:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
            Display display2 = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            int width = display2.getWidth();  
            int height = display2.getHeight(); 
            int realSize = width / 3;


        DatBas dbc = new DatBas(Tamar_appActivity.this);
        dbc.open();
        SQLiteDatabase tdb = dbc.getDatabase();
        String[] columns = new String[] { DatBas.KEY_ROW_B_ID,
                DatBas.KEY_B_NAME };
        Cursor c = tdb.query(DatBas.DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();
        int iRawBId = c.getColumnIndex(DatBas.KEY_ROW_B_ID);
        int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(DatBas.KEY_B_NAME);
        int iBimage = c.getColumnIndex(DatBas.KEY_B_IMAGE_PATH);
//      ic_launcher.png
        int cursorSize = c.getCount();
        int rows = (cursorSize / 3) + 1; // +1 so you have at least one row if the number of button is below 3
        int current = 1; // starting position
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            TableRow tr1 = new TableRow(this);
            tr1.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (current <= cursorSize) {
                    SpecialButton sb = new SpecialButton(this);
                    sb.text.setText(c.getString(iBName));
                    sb.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(realSize,
                            realSize));
                    // other stuff you would do
//                  sb.image.getDrawable();
                    tr1.addView(sb);
                    c.moveToNext();
                }
                current++;
            }
            tl.addView(tr1);
        }
        dbc.close();

    }
```

Comment: I don't think anyone understood to much from your question. Maybe an image with the layout you want will help.

Comment: I am sorry, I have edit my question and uploaded an image.

Answer (score 0):

> I wold like that this buttons will shows as a Circle (Drawable),
>   within that Circle there is an image (the path will be taken from the
>   database), and a label from the above explanation (from a table).

I would recommend you to make a layout file to simulate all the items:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!-- This will hold the image from the database -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/anchor"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <!-- This will be the label. It will be placed below the center -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/anchor"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</merge>
```

The `item_background` drawable used above:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <solid android:color="#92c47d" />

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#000000" />

</shape>
```

Then you'll probably want to put this in a custom `View` class for easy handling:

```
    public class SpecialButton extends RelativeLayout {

    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;

    public SpecialButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.item_background1);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.views_special_btn_layout,
                this, true);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    }

    public SpecialButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public SpecialButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

}
```

To simulate a `Button` add a `OnCLickListener` to the above custom view. There is no way to make a circle in a xml drawable(as far as I know) so if you don't have an exact size for the custom `View` above(like a value of `100dp`) you'll have calculate it in code. Also if you want to place the `TextView` *label* at some specific position you'll have to do it in code again. I don't know exactly how do you want the buttons to be placed on the screen, but normally  you would find out the width and height of the screen and work the real dimension from that:

```
// in the onCreate method
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  
int height = display.getHeight(); 
// here I assumed you have only 3 buttons and you want them to be placed taking all
// the width of the screen(of course this isn't ideal because if the user turns the
// phone, in landscape, you'll end up with 3 really big buttons so you may want to   
// set a default size for the buttons )
int realSize = width / 3; 
Cursor c = tdb.query(DatBas.DATABASE_TABLE_SETTINGS, columns, null,
            null, null, null, null);
    int iRawBId = c.getColumnIndex(DatBas.KEY_ROW_ID);
    int iBName = c.getColumnIndex(DatBas.KEY_B_NAME);
    int cursorSize = c.getCount();
    int rows = (cursorSize / 3) + 1; // +1 so you have at least one row if the number of button is below 3
    int current = 1; // starting position
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            if (current <= cursorSize) {
                SpecialButton sb = new SpecialButton(this);
                sb.text.setText(c.getString(iBName));
                sb.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(realSize,
                        realSize));
                // other stuff you would do
                tr.addView(sb);
                c.moveToNext();
            }
            current++;
        }
        tl.addView(tr);
    }
```

> If there is a one item, it will be in the center of the screen, and as
>   the amount of the buttons growth, the Circles will set within a Grid
>   of 3 columns.

I don't know your current layout but this could be done very easy in a layout like this(I assumed that you want to place the items in a `TableLayout`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/grid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then you would place your elements in code(each 3 items in a `TableRow`) and the `gravity`  of the parent `LinearLayout` attribute should place them in the center. You could use a `GridView` instead of a `TableLayout` but you'll have to work hard to center the items. The example for the 3 Buttons above:

```
       // in the onCreate method
       tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.grid);
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int width = display.getWidth();  
        int height = display.getHeight(); 
        int realSize = width / 3;
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        SpecialButton sb1 = new SpecialButton(this);
        sb1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(realSize, realSize));
        SpecialButton sb2 = new SpecialButton(this);
        sb2.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(realSize, realSize));
        SpecialButton sb3 = new SpecialButton(this);
        sb3.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(realSize, realSize));
        tr.addView(sb1);
        tr.addView(sb2);
        tr.addView(sb3);
        tl.addView(tr);
```

Comment: Thanks! What will be the recomendad way to configure it on a Java code? I have set within my answer the way I made it before I was decide to make it in the above way. and it was with radioButtons.

Comment: @Dori I've edited my answer(read the whole answer). I've seen your code but I don't see how you could achieve what you want with the `RadioGroups` and simple **`Buttons`**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I think I am trying to get the idea, but if i wold like to get those buttons dynamically, and populate the ImageView and the TextView out from the database (you can see the cursor above), what should be the way? i have set the imageview and the textview variables within the class specialButtons (    ImageView ivby = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageBB);
    TextView tvby = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.cbTextView);) and i cannot access them with "SpecialButtons.tvby.setText..."

Comment: Thanks again! I having this error when trying to run it on the emulator. what should be the reason? "Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 3 "

Comment: @Dori A query to the database returns a `Cursor` that has its starting position placed at `-1`(outside the values range). Call either `cursor.moveToFirst()` `cursor.moveToNext()` to place the `Cursor` at position `0` before you try to use it to extract data.

Comment: Ok i understand, but in which way can i set the position on the cursor?

Comment: @Dori The methods above will place the cursor at the first position (if you call them once for the `Cursor`). You also have `cursor.moveToPosition(thePositionOnTheCursor);` to move the `Cursor` to a specific position.

Comment: now it gives to me the following error: 06-05 06:58:51.409: E/AndroidRuntime(416): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException. Is this means that i did not set the image? of so, is there a way to set default image?

Comment: @Dori It means that somewhere in your code you have a reference that is `null` and you try to work with it. I can't guess what it is because I don't see what you're doing.

Comment: I am sorry but I try'd to find any null reference and without success. Do you see any thing there that can caused the error? (I have edit my original question)

Comment: @Dori I can't see where is the problem. Check the *line* where the `NullPointerException` occurs an work from there. See if you have a `TableLayout` with the id `R.id.grid` or if it isn't something in your database.

Comment: Ok After I found that the problem (as for now), is that I cannot to setText on the text field that sets on the SpecialButton.xml. What can be the reason?

Comment: Someone Can help me with that?